# How to run two separate xslt substring operations on a single xml node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a block of xml-tagged text produced from a database query, that is in (I think) /record/scope/scope, and I need to do two operations on it:
1) Convert line breaks to `<br /`> tags
2) Using the resulting output, check whether there are more than 350 characters in the entire string. If so, display the first 350 characters with a Show More link after it; when the Show More link is clicked, the entire text should display (including the breaks), and there should be a Show Less link at the end. When Show Less is clicked, only the 350 characters should display. (If there are no more than 350 characters then the entire block should display without the Show More/Show Less links.)

I am able to do each of these things separately (using code that someone else wrote) however I cannot figure out how to combine these two operations.

I've tried putting the output from the first operation (which is a call-template to code someone else wrote) into a variable, however I don't know how to run the second operation on that variable.

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<adlibXML>
<recordList>
<record priref="547" created="2016-11-13T12:55:00"     modification="2019-09-13T11:48:17" selected="false">
<scope>
<scope>
The Marjorie Best papers span the years 1934-1965 (bulk 1947-1965) and encompass 3.8 linear feet. The collection consists primarily of script material, wardrobe plots, and costume sketches. Eight of the scripts are signed by the cast and several are annotated. Wardrobe plots, many with cloth swatches attached, document Best's work on more than 30 films. The document boxes contain more than 40 costume sketches, including signed sketches for "Look for the Silver Lining" (1948).

Three flat boxes contain oversize costume sketches for 32 films from 1938 to 1965, including "The Adventures of Don Juan" (1949), "The Adventures of Marco Polo" (1938), "Giant" (1956), "The Greatest Story Ever Told" (1965), "Rio Bravo" (1959), "Sunrise at Campobello" (1960), "That Hamilton Woman!" (1941), and "The Time, the Place and the Girl" (1947). 
</scope>
</scope>
</record>
</recordList>
</adlibXML>
```

Here is the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL    /Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:template match="record">
      <xsl:call-template name="record" />
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="record">
  <!-- Scope notes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="scope/scope" />
 </xsl:template>


<!-- This template and the next one together insert <br /> in place of a line break. -->
<xsl:template match="scope">    
<xsl:variable name="formatted">
  <xsl:call-template name="replace-newline">
     <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable> 
  <xsl:copy-of select="$formatted"/> 
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="replace-newline">
<xsl:param name="text" select="."/>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&#xA;')">
    <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&#xA;')"/>
    <br />
    </p>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-newline">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>



<!-- This template checks the length of the content and puts the links if necessary. -->

<xsl:template match="scope">
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="string-length(.) &gt; 355" >
<xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 355 + string-length(substring-before(substring(., 355),' ')))" />
   <div class="toggle-group">
    <div class="toggle-group show-label script">
      <a>Show more...</a>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-group children">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 355  + string-length(substring-before(substring(., 355),' ')))" />
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-group hide-label script">
      <a> Show less...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
     </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>    
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't think I can give a true working example because there are so so many dependencies not all of which I can share, but I think basically the HTML would look like this:

```
<p>The Marjorie Best papers span the years 1934-1965 (bulk 1947-1965) and encompass 3.8 linear feet. The collection consists primarily of script material, wardrobe plots, and costume sketches. Eight of the scripts are signed by the cast and several are annotated. Wardrobe plots, many with cloth swatches attached, document Best's work on more than 30 films.
<div class="toggle-group">
<div class="toggle-group show-label script">
<a>Show more...</a>
<br></div>
<div class="toggle-group children"> The document boxes contain more than 40 costume sketches, including signed sketches for "Look for the Silver Lining" (1948).
<br/>
</p>Three flat boxes contain oversize costume sketches for 32 films from 1938 to 1965, including "The Adventures of Don Juan" (1949), "The Adventures of Marco Polo" (1938), "Giant" (1956), "The Greatest Story Ever Told" (1965), "Rio Bravo" (1959), "Sunrise at Campobello" (1960), "That Hamilton Woman!" (1941), and "The Time, the Place and the Girl" (1947).</div>
<div class="toggle-group hide-label script">
<a> Show less...</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the exact HTML code you want to get as the result?

Comment: Ok yes, it will take me a little while to come up with that.

Comment: I added it to the original writeup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what the exact output should be. The following example shows how you can combine the two operations, using some arbitrary assumptions:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="/adlibXML">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="recordList/record/scope/scope" />
        </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="scope"> 
    <div>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 350">  
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-newline">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring(., 1, 350)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <div class="toggle-group">
                    <div class="toggle-group show-label script">
                        <a>Show more...</a>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="toggle-group children">
                        <xsl:call-template name="replace-newline">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring(., 351)"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toggle-group hide-label script">
                        <a> Show less...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-newline">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring(., 1, 350)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace-newline">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&#xA;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&#xA;')"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-newline">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```